# Java/jmeter http request fails but curl works

Tags: java, jmeter

I am trying a very basic http request with jmeter, but it seems to always get the error below. I have tried a simple get against google which is fine but the internal servers are not :

`java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host (Host unreachable)`

I can curl the same url successfully with a 200 response, so not sure if its jmeter or java? The only thing that is unique is that our internal servers are resolving with ipv6, but I would not think that would be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried with the IP? Does it return the same error?

Comment: What's your java version?

Comment: I was 1.8 on mac default, but upgrading to oracle 9, and adding the below params seems to have solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the next line to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
java.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true
```

Or pass the aforementioned property via -D command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses=true -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

References:

- [Java: Networking Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/doc-files/net-properties.html)
- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Comment: Still no luck running with the change to system.properties as well as running as using the -D option, I have limited to a single request.

I have also tried "Follow redirects" + "Redirect Automatically" with no luck.

Comment: ok, i have isolated it specifically to a java configuration issue, by curling directly with java and getting the same error. Still no closer to a solution though.

Comment: almost 4 years have passed. Did you eventually solve the problem?